# Extract name attribute for multiple input fields and store in an array without using for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a form with multiple fields each has a name attribute, how can I extract these name attributes and store in an array or something for future use?

```js
var inputs = $("input[type='text']"),
  outputs = [];
$("#submit").click(function() {
  inputs.each(function() {
    outputs.push(inputs.attr("name"));
  });
  console.log(outputs)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename" name="forename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="middlename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Lastname">
  Lastname
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="lastname">
</div>
<p id="message"></p>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
```

`outputs` is still empty after clicking the button, why are the strings not being pushed into the empty array?

Comment: *"`outputs` is still empty after clicking the button"* No, it isn't. Your snippet doesn't ever use `outputs` **after** clicking the button. I copied it, added `console.log(outputs)` to just after the `each` call in the `click` handler, and `outputs` has the names in it. **Edit:** mplungjan changed your snippet to output `outputs`. Now it has the first name repeated in it, because you're doing `inputs.attr("name")`, not `this.name`. Use `this.name` to access the name for the input the `each` loop is visiting.

Comment: Yes I had to add the console.log where I added it. You cannot show it outside the submit

Comment: @mplungjan - I edited the comment after you edited the snippet. Using `this.name` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputs` is a jQuery collection. You will get the first element of that collection every time you only access `inputs` But if you loop over `inputs` with `each`, then $(this).attr("name) or this.name will return the attribute of each element

PS: `.each` IS a for loop - here is some of the code from the jQuery.js file

```
if ( isArrayLike( obj ) ) {
  length = obj.length;
  for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
    if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

You have several possibilities

**$(this).attr("name")**  or **this.name**

```js
var $inputs = $("input[type='text']"),
  outputs = [];
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $inputs.each(function() {
    outputs.push($(this).attr("name")); // $(this) is the input;  this.name works too
  });
  console.log(outputs)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename" name="forename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="middlename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Lastname">
  Lastname
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="lastname">
</div>
<p id="message"></p>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
```

**accessing the input's DOM node using the parameters passed to the function**

```js
var inputs = $("input[type='text']"),
  outputs = [];
$("#submit").click(function() {
  inputs.each(function(_,inp) { // inp is the DOM node
    outputs.push(inp.name);
  });
  console.log(outputs)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename" name="forename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="middlename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Lastname">
  Lastname
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="lastname">
</div>
<p id="message"></p>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
```

**Use a map:**

```js
let outputs;
$("#submit").click(function() {
  outputs = $("input[type='text']").map((_,inp) => inp.name).get()
  console.log(outputs)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename" name="forename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="middlename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Lastname">
  Lastname
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="lastname">
</div>
<p id="message"></p>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: Surely this is more of a comment and close-as-typo situation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - or a dupe, but I added some more information

Comment: What's the difference here between `$(this)` and directly using the variable `inputs`? I thought both would work?

Comment: Inputs is a jQuery collection. You will get the first element of that collection every time you only access `inputs` But if you loop over `inputs` with each then `$(this).attr("name)` or `this.name` will return the attribute of each element